# $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{x,y\}$ fundmental group.

Tags: algebraic-topology

So im trying to show that the plane minus two points is homotopy equivalent to the figure 8 and show its fundamental group is the free group on 2 generators.

So I know by Van Kampen, I can write

$\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{x,y\}= \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{x\} \cup \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{y\}$

Where the first set on the RHS ill denote $U$ and the second set as $V$.

And since the plane minus a point is homeomorphic to the circle which has fundamental group the integers so we have a product of integers. But how do we guarantee this product is free? is it because their intersection is the whole plane?

Comment: There are no relations so all elements have infinite order. Each copy has fundamental group isomorphic to the integers which is free so you get the free product.

Comment: The equality $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{x,y\}= \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{x\} \cup \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{y\}
$ is very false.

Comment: You say in the first sentence that you want to show it is homotopy equivalent to figure $8$. Then why are you calculating fundamental group? That is not enough. And once you establish it, you can calculate fundamental group of the figure $8$ instead.

Comment: (it is actually equivalent, because both spaces have the homotopy type of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces, but of course that's not exactly a geodesic argument for this!)

Answer (score 0):

With van Kampen you get a free product with amalgamation $\pi_1(U\cap V,x_0)=0.$  Pretty clear $U\cap V$ has the homotopy type of a point,  right? You've got the wedge sum of two circles.   The intersection is contractible.

What you wrote isn't quite right.  Instead: $$\Bbb R^2\setminus \{x,y\}\cong S^1\vee S^1.$$

So let $U=S^1\setminus\{\text{pt.}\}=V.$

The open sets are then $S^1\vee V$ and $U\vee S^1.$  And their intersection is then contractible.

So it's $\pi_1(S^1)*\pi_1(S^1)/\{0\}\cong\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z.$

Comment: The intersection of what is a point?

Comment: Correction.   See my edit.  @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: If $U$ and $V$ are as in the question, this does not work since (i) the equation in the question is wrong and (ii) $U \cap V$ does not have the homotopy type of a point.

Comment: How do I write down the explicit homotopy between R minus two points and the wedge of two circles?

Comment: If you start with the homotopy equivalence from $\mathbb{R}^2 \smallsetminus {pt}$ to $S^1$, what you can do is WLOG assume $x$ is at $(-1,0)$ and $y$ is at $(1,0)$, then on the left half of $\mathbb{R}^2$ use the homotopy equivalence to a small circle around $x$ (say, of radius $1/2$) together with a "whisker" line segment from $(-1/2,0)$ to the origin (do the inverse of the homotopy equivalence collapsing that line segment to a point). Do the analogous thing on the right half of $\mathbb{R}^2$, giving you a shape like O--O. Then contract the connecting line segment.

Comment: You may need to slightly modify your formula so that all points along the $y$-axis go to the origin under your homotopies. An explicit formula isn't so illuminating (and annoying to figure out how to write down), but the geometric picture should be pretty clear.